# how to enter other activity from listfragment java class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to create list view in listfragment and on click of list, want to go other activity. Plz help to achieve this.

`Intent I=new Intent();` giving errors as it is not taking listfragment as an activity

Comment: you need to go from activity to activity.  Call back to your activity and then start the intent from there

Comment: @Kalininskaya who said you can't go to activity from fragment?

Comment: use getActivity() instead of ActivityName.this in intent

Comment: but I want to create listview inside the listfragment and want to perform each list on click to go to other activity .Plz tell me how to achieve this in nutshell.Just like Gmail which has listfragment which again on click create list view which further on click open new page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can open activity from the fragment.

Use like this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivityClass.class));
```

and this statement will open your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
             startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivityName.class));   
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but the listview created in xml file should be given reference by R.layout...... file .Then where to put these xml file reference .I want the gmail like structure which as listfragment which further has listview .And on click of these list ,new page opens.

Comment: is your listview populated with data?

Comment: This is my mainactivity.java